# Why is the pointer in this MSDN example not deleted?

Tags: c++, pointers, directx, msdn

I was looking at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476877(v=vs.85).aspx) which talks about how to enumerate through graphics adapters on a computer.  In the following code sample, I noticed that `IDXGIAdapter * pAdapter` is never explicitly deleted.  My amateur C++ brain sees this as a memory leak.  Is there a reason why this would not be deleted?

```
std::vector <IDXGIAdapter*> EnumerateAdapters(void)
{
    IDXGIAdapter * pAdapter; 
    std::vector <IDXGIAdapter*> vAdapters; 
    IDXGIFactory* pFactory = NULL; 


    // Create a DXGIFactory object.
    if(FAILED(CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory) ,(void**)&pFactory)))
    {
        return vAdapters;
    }


    for ( UINT i = 0;
          pFactory->EnumAdapters(i, &pAdapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND;
          ++i )
    {
        vAdapters.push_back(pAdapter); 
    } 


    if(pFactory)
    {
        pFactory->Release();
    }

    return vAdapters;

}
```

Comment: You generally don't want to explicitly delete any object inheriting from `IUnknown`, as the majority of DirectX objects are. Call `Release()` on them instead. In this particular case you shouldn't even release it because it's stored in a vector and used afterwards.

Comment: As a general rule, you must match allocation method and deallocation method. So `new[ ]` matches `delete[ ]`, not `delete`, there's the pair `malloc/free` and COM has it's own `AddRef/Release` pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IDXGIAdapter` ultimately derives from `IUnknown`, which is the base class (COM interface) of almost any DirectX-related class.

As such, you should generally not call `delete` on them explicitly. Instead, you want to use the COM method `Release()` which internally decrements the reference count of the object and deletes it automatically if necessary. Think of it as a sort of smart pointer.

In this specific example, the pointer is inserted into a `std::vector` and such a vector is returned. So you must not release it, otherwise it would become a dangling pointer.

Comment: The better solution here is to use ``std::vector<Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter*>>``